# Statistical Physics: How do we derive this equation?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, pressure

I'm reading through *Statistical Physics* by F. Mandl and there is a step in arriving at an equation that I don't follow.

He uses
$$P = \sum_r p_r \left(-\frac{\mathrm dE_r}{\mathrm dV} \right) \tag{4.8}$$

to arrive at

$$P = \frac{1}{\beta} \left(\frac{\partial \ln Z}{\partial V}\right)_{\beta} \, . \tag{4.10}$$

He says that this is analogous to

$$\bar E = \sum_r p_rE_r = -\frac{\partial \ln Z}{\partial \beta} \tag{2.26}$$

and also hints that equation 4.10 is a direct result of differentiation of

$$Z = \sum_r e^{-\beta E_r} \, . \tag{2.23}$$

I don't see the connection. How did he do it?

Comment: So you're looking for a justification of the result 4.10?  Would you be willing to accept a thermodynamical expression for pressure as a starting point?

Comment: @Joshphysics sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A self-contained, careful derivation of (4.10):

1. We consider a thermodynamic system whose state can be characterized by the macroscopic variables $(S, V, N)$, then starting with the fundamental relationship $\mathrm dU = T\,\mathrm dS -P\,\mathrm dV + \mu\,\mathrm dN$, and noting that $\beta = 1/(k T)$, one can deduce the following useful expression for the system's pressure as a function of the state variables $(\beta,V,N)$:
   $$
     P = \frac{1}{k\beta}\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_{\beta, N} - \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_{\beta, N}
   $$
2. Using the following definitions of entropy $S$, macroscopic energy $U$, and the partition function $Z$:
   $$
     S = -k\sum_i p_i\ln p_i, \qquad U = \sum_i p_i E_i, \qquad Z = \sum_ie^{-\beta E_i}, \qquad p_i = \frac{e^{-\beta E_i}}{Z}
   $$
   one can deduce the following expression for the entropy:
   $$
     S = k\beta U + k\ln Z
   $$
3. Plugging the expression for the entropy from step 2 into the expression for the pressure in step 1 gives precisely the desired result.

For now, I leave the nitty gritty details to the reader because they are a good exercise, but more detail can be provided if requested.

**Addendum.** Comments on an alternative viewpoint.

If you're unwilling to take the expression for pressure in step 1 above as a starting point, then here are another line of reasoning that it seems Mandl is suggesting:

1. Assume that the energies $E_i$ of the system at hand can be written as functions of $(V, N)$ (e.g. for $N$ non-interacting quantum particles in a box), assume that the macroscopic pressure equals the negative average change in energy for a given change in volume when the particle number is held fixed, and use the shorthand $\partial/\partial V = (\partial/\partial_V)_{\beta, N}$, then
   $$
     P 
   = \sum_i p_i \left[-\frac{\partial E_i}{\partial V}\right] 
   = \sum_i\left[\frac{\partial p_i}{\partial V}E_i - \frac{\partial (p_iE_i)}{\partial V}\right] = \sum_i\frac{\partial p_i}{\partial V}E_i - \frac{\partial U}{\partial V}
   $$
2. Use the statistical definition of entropy (see above) and the fact that probabilities sum to one, to obtain
   $$
     \frac{1}{k\beta}\frac{\partial S}{\partial V} = \sum_i\frac{\partial p_i}{\partial V} E_i 
   $$
3. Combine steps 1 and 2, restoring the more descriptive derivative notation to obtain the result
   $$
     P = \frac{1}{k\beta}\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_{\beta, N} - \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_{\beta, N}
   $$
   without appealing to the fundamental relation $\mathrm dU = T\,\mathrm dS -P\,\mathrm dV + \mu\,\mathrm dN$.
4. Continue with the original step 2 before the addendum.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat Yes.  See the addendum.  Note that whatever method you use, the trick is deciding what you're willing to accept as the mathematical expression for pressure as your starting point.

Comment: Wait, this might be a really dumb question but isn't $\sum_i \frac{\partial p_i}{\partial V} E_i=0$? Because $\sum_i p_i =1$ and $\sum_i dp_i = 0$

Comment: I tried to derive how you got your expression for $S$ in the original step 2, but no luck. I got as far as $S=k \ln Z -k\sum_i p_i \ln e^{-\beta E_i}$. Any more tips?

Comment: @whatwhatwhat Note that $\sum_i \frac{\partial p_i}{\partial V} = \frac{\partial}{\partial V}\sum_i p_i = \frac{\partial}{\partial V} 1 = 0$, but with the $E_i$ in the sum, you cannot do this sort of thing to get zero.  As for the entropy expression, you're very close.  The log and exponential undo one another, so you get $-k\sum_ip_i(-\beta E_i) = k\beta \sum_ip_iE_i = k\beta U$.

Comment: How did you go from $P 
= \sum_i p_i \left[-\frac{\partial E_i}{\partial V}\right]$ to $
= \sum_i\left[\frac{\partial p_i}{\partial V}E_i - \frac{\partial (p_iE_i)}{\partial V}\right]$ ?? I can't figure this part out. By the way, thanks$\cdot 10^{999999}$ for helping me through this!

Comment: @whatwhatwhat Expand the second term in brackets using the product rule for differentiation.  I think I'm gonna let you grapple with the rest.  It's good for character-building :)

Comment: *Facepalm* I figured it out and, again, it was so simple... I appreciate all your patience. Thank you!!